# Switched to SSL now PHP sessions require two tries

Tags: php, session, ssl

I had a pretty good homebrew login setup on my site using both a local registry and working with Facebook, Google, and Twitters 3rd party auth tools.

But now that I've secured the site with an SSL cert it seems to have been borked in an odd way. As near as I can tell, the Sessions won't take the first go around, but try again and the session kick in, it was working fine before the SSL switch over, so I feel like I'm missing something related there.

Is there something I should be paying attention to in particular? Some sort of common misstep for someone that has never used PHP sessions in an SSL environment perhaps?

Comment: You have to do `session_start()` twice or `$_SESSION['index']` twice to get the value?

Comment: are there any instances of `http://` anywhere? and I mean "any". Such as in any files including js/css/img/ etc. this could affect how your SSL-environment scripts work/behave.

Comment: stayed as long as I could; ping someone/me. I had to leave. Question's unclear btw.

Comment: @KDOT: I only have the one `session_start()` at the beginning of the index, and thats predicated on there not being one already

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm fairly certain I hunted down all the `http:` entries, but I'll have another go at it

Comment: even if there is "one" (`http://` js/css/img/php/txt/etc.) that could affect something. It's best to always use `//` for scripts/js etc. so that it auto-populates to either `http://` or `https://` respectively. `<img src="/folder/file.jpg">` should always be pointing to the root/folder rather than `<img src="http://example.com/file.jpg">` as an example. Hard to say why yours is failing since we don't know what the server/folder/file structure is.

Comment: @Fred-ii- its a weird sort of failing, inconsistent; imagine you click the Facebook icon to be authenticated via Facebook on a website, and it redirects you as it should to the origin page, but the session doesn't kick in, so you click it again, but this time it does. I would think this is a service provider issue if didn't happen for all providers including my local username/password setup.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out in this case, watch out for missing "www" at the beginning of redirect URLs.